# Set selected item in MvxSpinner in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I want to set a selected item of MvxSpinner in mvvmcross.

```
    public class EditProfileViewModel 
        : MvxViewModel
    {
        public class Districts
        {
            public Districts(string name)
            {
                Name = name;
            }

            public string Name { get; private set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                var rhs = obj as Districts;
                if (rhs == null)
                    return false;
                return rhs.Name == Name;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                if (Name == null)
                    return 0;
                return Name.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        private List<Districts> _items = new List<Districts>();
        public List<Districts> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items); }
        }

        private Districts _item= new Districts("Solapur");
        public Districts Item
        {
            get { return _item; }
            set { _item = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Item); }
        }
  }
```

And my corresponding layout is as follows

```
<MvxSpinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/district_spinner"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/district_spinnerdropdown"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;SelectedItem Item" />
```

But it is not giving any error.But item is not get selected in spinner.
But spinner contains all the items in it but without selected any item in it.

Comment: @Stuart , Sir.Please help me.

Comment: How do you populate the list of Items?

Comment: I have assigned values to my List of items in one of my method which is called in Init() method of this viewModel.

Comment: There is a working sample for MvxSpinner in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/Resources/Layout/Test_Spinner.axml - make sure your list or observablecollection is filled and bound before your selecteditem is set